# Get first x number of elements from a hashmap in clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap

How does one retrieve the first x key value pairs from a sorted clojure map of 2x key value pairs

Comment: Actually, your map is either sorted or hashed, but not both. You can take the _first_ n pairs for both, but for the hash map, the pairs you will get are undetermined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `take` on a `sorted-map`:

```
(def a (sorted-map 3 :a 2 :b 1 :c))
(take 2 a)      ;;  ([1 :c] [2 :b])
```